# restrict sign and signup page after auth nextauth nextjs

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I'm trying to restrict sign and signup page after auth in nextauth nextjs through the given middleware:

```js
import { getToken } from "next-auth/jwt";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function middleware(req) {
  const url = req.nextUrl.clone();
  url.pathname = "/auth/new-user";
  if (req.nextUrl.pathname === "/" || req.nextUrl.pathname === "/settings") {
    const session = await getToken({
      req,
      secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
      secureCookie: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
    });
    // You could also check for any property on the session object,
    // like role === "admin" or name === "John Doe", etc.
    if (!session) return NextResponse.redirect(url);
    // If user is authenticated, continue.
  }
}
```

where it restricts the path '/' if the user is not auth which works great. but after auth the user is able to go back and see the sign in and sign up pages...

I was thinking of doing something like

```js
    if (!session){
      return NextResponse.redirect(url);
    }else{
      return NextResponse.redirect('/')
    }
```

This still doesn't account for the other pages that need to be accounted for after the user is authenticated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

restrict make 2 different portions to differentiate between auth and after auth

```js
export async function middleware(req) {
  const auth = req.nextUrl.clone();
  auth.pathname = "/auth/new-user";
  const afterAuth = req.nextUrl.clone();
  afterAuth.pathname = "/";

  if (req.nextUrl.pathname === "/" || req.nextUrl.pathname === "/settings") {
    const session = await getToken({
      req,
      secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
      secureCookie: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
    });
    // You could also check for any property on the session object,
    // like role === "admin" or name === "John Doe", etc.
    if (!session) return NextResponse.redirect(auth);
    // If user is authenticated, continue.
  }

  if (req.nextUrl.pathname === "/auth/new-user" || req.nextUrl.pathname === "/auth/signin") {
    const session = await getToken({
      req,
      secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
      secureCookie: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
    });
    // You could also check for any property on the session object,
    // like role === "admin" or name === "John Doe", etc.
    if (session) return NextResponse.redirect(afterAuth);
    // If user is authenticated, continue.
  }
}
```